# Does Android Natively Support text-based formats?

Tags: android, text, native

I am aware of the website http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html but that only shows what's supported in terms of media, i was wondering if anyone knows if .txt has a native API that supports it?

Note that I am mainly concerned with the parsing of .TXT

Answer (score 0):

Media formats is about video/images/sounds. Text based format is really too broad description. Java supports reading text files, then you are welcome to do whatever you need to. DOC is a binary format and there's no API in Android to read it. You might want to search for some java class which allows reading it.

Answer (score 0):

.txt is basically just plain text anyway. That's how I save any text files in java as well. Pretty simple really. I've heard there is some apache library (the word is escaping me right now) that handles I/O better than what is normally done in java.

Answer (score 0):

since there is no out of the box api, this is how i would parse a txt file.

```
final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/MyFolder/MyFile.txt");          
final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
    // parse line here  
}
```

though i would **handle exceptions**